# Google Cloud App Engine Firewall: simply disallow all and allow a home IP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have read a lot on GCP's Firewall rules and even got help from a dev-ops person who could not understand why these rules block my home IP from my **App Engine Standard F1** instance.

```
Priority T    Action    IP range
2000          Allow     XX.X.XX.XXX
2001          Allow     xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx // my V6 IP
default       Deny      *
```

When adding the V6 IP
I am allowed access but with strange errors, eg. refreshing the page shows a path error: But browsing there (or to any path) loads just fine.

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /feed was not found on this server.
```

Without the V6 IP (and only the V4 IP allow rule) I cannot access the instance.

How can I whitelist my own IP for access?

Comment: Your question detail is unclear to me. I assume (!?) you're using App Engine flex not standard, correct? App Engine standard does not sit behind Compute Engine firewalls. Where are you configuring the firewall? Are you using the VPC firewall? i.e. https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list

Comment: Hello @DazWilkin, the AE is Standard F1. I have never seen that standard does not sit behind a firewall and perhaps is not the case because the deny rule is in effect.

Comment: App Engine standard and App Engine flex use different firewalls. I created an App Engine standard app and applied a firewall using the value from [What is my IP?](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip). It works correctly but I don't have an IPv6 address to test. I recommend you file an issue on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetrack.google.com)

Comment: I've also made some test using my IPv4 and IPv6 and got the same results as you.
As pointed out by this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1199141/1539601) and this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/403731/1539601), it seems the connections are preferred to be done over IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @RogelioMonter this IPV6 must be the answer because V4 doesnt allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reviewed in the comments, from the test I've made, I can confirm that connections are preferred to be done over IPv6 rather than IPv4.

As pointed out by this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/403731/1539601):

> The first thing that a client determines is which protocols are available. ...It will then do a DNS lookup for both the A (IPv4 address) and AAAA (IPv6 address) records. If only one type is returned then it will use that. If both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are returned the default behaviour depends a bit on the client software. Usually  [RFC 3484](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt)  is used.
>
> According to the official standards it should prefer IPv6...

You can confirm this behaviour by checking into the logs the IP address that reaches the service of which you are testing the firewall rules (eg. *default* service); service, [using the Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/viewing-service-logs#using-logs-viewer).

[image: Legacy Logs Viewer]

Look up for a Log entry that matches a request you made (eg. to the `/`
root directory).

To show the latest logs, click **Jump to now**.

[image: Time-range selector is used for selecting time range.]

Under `httpRequest` on the field `remoteIp` you could check the IP address that your machine is using to access App Engine.

*In order to do this, delete the rules you've created and change the default rule to `Allow`.*